# How to personally separate questions into separate groups/folders?

Tags: feature-request

Can I mark questions into a personally defined categories A,B,C, and choose to view a certain category; or choose to not view a certain category?

I view the stream of questions. Get interested in one, spend some time on it, then come back for viewing the list again. The problem is that I go through much of what I sifted through and have to screen them out again to find a question I may be interested in.

So I want a way of taking questions off of my list that I know reasonably well  that I will not be following.

There is a way of making a question a favorite. But there is no way I see of taking questions off of the master list viewed by one person.

Comment: [Managing favorites](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3639/19341)...:-(pending)-:...

Comment: Can you not open questions which look interesting in tabs? That's what I do. It only works for one browser session, sure, but it sounds like that is all you are needing?

Comment: You can completely hide the ignored tags, but there is no way to hide a particular question from the view permanently. I can imagine that a GreaseMonkey script similar to those at stackapps.com could accomplish the task, but it seems there isn't one already made.

Comment: @PavelM What is/what do you mean by "the ignored tags"?

Comment: Look at the right column of the main site: it has `Favorite tags` with a field where you can add them, and similarly for `Ignored tags`. By default questions with ignored tags are grayed out on the page. But if you go to your profile -> prefs and check "hide ignored tags", they'll be hidden forever. // Disclosure: I do it for a  number of very popular tags on this site. // You can also add a tag  to either list by hovering over tag name (like feature-request under your question) and clicking the little star there: it cycles through grey star = neutral, gold star = favorite, red X = ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filters.

http://stackexchange.com/filters